# shutdown / undeploy tomcat from Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, shutdown

I have an init servlet in Tomcat that loads critical data.  Sometimes it is necessary to abort startup on certain errors.

how do i gracefully shutdown the deployed app/ the whole app server without calling `System.exit(1)`

i want to avoid calling the shutdown servlet via port, since this is not configured in my installation.

there may be tasks that need to be run from listeners on shutdown defined in web.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should never ever ever ever call `System.exit()` from within a servlet container, as there might be other applications running within the same process as yours, and it would be incredibly incorrect to forcibly kill the entire process.

Assuming your "init servlet" implements `ServletContextListener`, there is no formal way defined in the API/interface to signal to the servlet container "please shut down the app neatly". You could however throw some sort of `RuntimeException` from the `contextInitialized()` method, which in most containers (at least Tomcat) will stop the startup of your webapp and leave it in the "stopped" state. However I doubt that Tomcat will continue to call your shutdown listeners.

You might want to rethink your design so that your critical data / shutdown logic is not tied so tightly with the lifecycle of the servlet container.

Comment: its more about shutting down utility threads and correctly writing logs

Comment: I used to share a Tomcat with a bad app which runs out of memory all the time. When I detect that, I call System.exit(0). The shutdown is as graceful as other approach in Tomcat.

Comment: Well if you're getting OOMs then at that point there's nothing left to do but shutdown the JVM.

Comment: If you are getting out-of-memory errors, you should be fixing that faulty servlet rather than making a habit of crashing your server with a `System.exit`.

Comment: One clarification: Your implementation of `ServletContextListener` needn't be a Servlet, it can be a POJO class that implements that interface of two methods. By the way, nowadays the easiest way to get your Servlet container to recognize, load, and execute your listener is to simply annotate with [@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html). Such a listener is the intended hook for you to perform your web app’s setup and teardown, guaranteed to run before/after the first/last servlet invocation.

Answer (score 0):

What I added was a healthcheck probe that would check if the server was still up using a `curl` I think it can be modified to check if a "flag" file is present as well.  I just send a `catalina.sh stop` command.

If this was a Docker container, you can use the healthcheck probe to let it close itself as well.

Ideally if you can migrate to something like Spring Boot which runs tomcat but terminates it if the Spring Context does not load properly.